# eclipse apostrophe not preceded by

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have many strings in my project that include apostrophes (') with no backslash and haven't had any problems until i added another string that happened to have an apostrphe and I'm receiving the

```
<string name="sec_fourth_para">The WRX\’s previous 2.0 liter engine was replaced with the 2.5 liter boxer engine.</string>
```

error: Apostrophe not proceeded by \

I've added the \ and I'm still receiving the error.  Searching brings up a similiar post that states the \ will fix this.  Any other suggestions besides to stop using Eclipse?

Comment: I have many strings with apostrophes. I ALWAYS prefix the apostrophe with a backslash. Never had a single problem. Maybe you were using backticks instead of apostrophes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the apostrophe you're using in this sentence is not the one as this [u+0027](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm) I guess you must have copy-pasted the text from somewhere. Just delete the apostrophe and re-type it.

[image]

Comment: I deleted the entire sentence and retyped WRX\'s and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

according to this table: [HTML codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

use the apostrophe code `&#39;` ( ', single quote)

```
<string name="sec_fourth_para">The WRX&#39;s previous 2.0 liter engine was replaced with the 2.5 liter boxer engine.</string>
```

or  `&#8217;` ( ’ , right single quotation mark)

```
<string name="sec_fourth_para">The WRX&#8217;s previous 2.0 liter engine was replaced with the 2.5 liter boxer engine.</string>
```

I reccomend the use html codes, for example i use the © copyright sign, then my string must be:

```
<string name="copyright_ap">&#169; Copyright</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work   or try with `&apos;`

```
The WRX`&apos;`s previous 2.0 liter engine was replaced with the 2.5 liter boxer engine.
```

Comment: I'm trying that and &#39; and I'm still getting error